# Custom form on SharePoint list is one step behind

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapps-forms

There are two types of tickets in my list, and since content type isn't currently accessible in PowerApps (Microsoft admits a bug on this one), I am simply storing a hardcoded text value instead of the content type name and reading from that field to perform my logic.  If the user clicks on item of type A then I want it to show the Type A display form, etc.

For the sake of illustration, let's say we have two items on the list, one of type A and one of type B.

Here's how it's currently flowing when the user performs these actions in sequence:

```
1) User clicks on item A,  Home screen opens.  (Should be View Type A screen)
2) User clicks on item A again, View Type A screen opens. (This is correct)
3) User clicks on item B,  View Type A opens but with item B data. (Clearly wrong)
4) User clicks on item B again,  View Type B opens with item B data (this is correct)
```

In all cases, whenever a screen is opening, it first displays the last-shown screen for a split second and then switches to the one it's really trying to display.

This is the code in my SharePointIntegration.OnView:

```
    Switch(SharePointIntegration.Selected.'My Text Field',
        "Type A", ViewForm(frmViewTypeA);Navigate(ViewTypeAScreen),
        "Type B", ViewForm(frmViewTypeB);Navigate(ViewTypeBScreen))
```

It feels to me like something isn't getting cleared or reset properly, but I don't know where else to look or what I'm looking for.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The official formula is as follows(FirstName is a text input control):

Switch( FirstName.Text, "Carlos", Navigate( Screen1, ScreenTransition.None ), "Kirstin", Navigate( Screen2, ScreenTransition.None ), "John", Navigate( Screen3, ScreenTransition.None ) )

Reference:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if#branching-in-behavior-formulas

Comment: Thank you, Julie.  It appears the only difference between my formula and yours was the ViewForm function, and that I'm not using a screen transition.  I removed the ViewForm functions, saved/published, opened a new browser and tried again, but still getting the same one-step-behind behavior. Didn't seem to make any difference.